# Counting letters of a sentence gives random ouput

Tags: c, arrays, string, scanf, fgets

I need my program to input the number of sentences the user wants to enter and then enter those sentences. Then, by passing it through the function `letter()`, I want it to count the number of times each letter is seen in the string. However, I am encountering the following problems:

1. When I enter the number of lines, the program only asks the user to enter 1 less than the number entered (i.e. if I want 2 sentences, I am only prompted for one).
2. The letter count does not work properly. It seems as though its kind of random.

Also I want to know if I am using my 2D array properly or not (i.e. Am I populating it properly and am I passing it through the function properly). For the array `str[][]`, I want the first box to represent the number of sentences and the second one to represent number of characters in each line.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void letter(int n, char str[][80]){
    char c = 'a';
    char alpha[26];
    int ltrcnt[26];

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        ltrcnt[i] = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k < 26; k++){
                if(str[i][j] == c){
                    ltrcnt[k]++;
                }
                c++;
            }
        }
    }

    c = 'a';
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        printf("%c: %d\n", c, ltrcnt[i]);
        c++;
    }
}   

int main(void){
    int n;

    printf("Enter number of lines: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    char str[n][80];
    printf("Enter a sentecne: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        fgets(str[i], 80, stdin);
    }

    letter(n, str);
}
```

Comment: with random you mean you can enter the same sentence twice and you get different results?

Answer (score 3):

**The first problem**, `fgets()` skipping one iteration is because of the leftover `newline` by press of <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key after the first input.

A simple case to clean the input buffer off the newline would be

```
 scanf("%d%*c", &n);  //eat the newline.
```

**For the second issue**, inside the functions, you have three nested loop which does not make sense. You're not using the value of `n`, anywhere. This does not make any sense and leads to the *garbage* output.

For example,

- You limit the index `j` to `25`, but actually you're accepting it to be as long as `79`.
- You have loop variable `k`, which is not used properly.

A sensible loop condition would be,

- `i` upto `n-1` (`i<n`) as the first index.
- `j` upto terminating null, (`arr[i][j]`)
- `k`, starting from `a`, until `z`, (`int k = 'a'; k < ('z' + 1 ) ; k++`) [Note: this counts only lowercase letters]

Comment: In that case `ltrcnt[k]++;` --> `ltrcnt[k-'a']++;`

Answer (score 1):

> When I enter the number of lines, the program only asks the user to enter 1 less than the number entered

I guess when you do the scanf, it doesn't swallow the new line at the end of the number. Thus the first `fgets` gets the (empty) remainder of the line with the number on it

> The letter count does not work properly. It seems as though its kind of random.

In your loop, `i` should count from `0` to `n - 1` (i.e. the number of lines in `str`) and `j` should count from 0 to `strlen(str[i]) - 1` or better, `j` should count from `0` to when `str[i][j] == '\0'` because `strlen` needs to iterate through all the characters itself and is thus inefficient.

Your inner loop should then see if `str[i][j]` is between `a` and `z` or `A` and `Z` and if it is, subtract `'a'` or `'A'` from it and use that as the index into `ltrcnt`

And by "inner loop", I mean the one with `j`, you don't need the `for (k ...` loop as far as I can see.

If you do insist on using the `k` loop, remember to reset `c` back to `'a'` before you start it each time.

The minimal fix for the second problem is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 0; str[i][j] != '\0'; j++){
        c = 'a'; // << was missing
        for(int k = 0; k < 26; k++){
            if(str[i][j] == c){
                ltrcnt[k]++;
            }
            c++;
        }
    }
}
```

A better fix that eliminates the innermost loop is

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 0; str[i][j] != '\0'; j++){
        if (str[i][j] >= 'a' && str[i][j] <= 'z')
        {
            ltrcnt[str[i][j] - 'a']++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I made the changes that you pointed out and the first problem was fixed. However, the second problem still remains. If i enter "how are you" and "my name is bob", it says the count for h is 2 and i is 1 and everything else is 0.

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed So it got the count for i right :) Your outer loop is `for (i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)` yes? and the j loop is `for (j = 0 ; str[i][j] != '\0' ; ++j)` yes? And before the k loop, you now have `c = 'a';`?

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. I forgot to set c = 'a' before the k loop and it makes sense that it was causing the issue. Thanks.